# .map() Function With ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, mapping

How would I go about using the map function via ES6?

This is what I have so far.

```
var names = ["Will", "Rick", "Blake"];

var formalGreeting = (name) => {
  names.map("Hello " + name);
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Awesome, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Map takes a function so you just need to add the `name =>` and return the value to push to the new array. This will get you started:

```js
const namesArray = ["Will", "Rick", "Blake"];

const formalGreeting = names => names.map(name => `Hello ${name}`);

console.log(formalGreeting(namesArray));
```

ES6 considerations:

- You don't need to wrap your code with `{}` for arrow functions that return one line of code
- You should be using [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) and [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) to declare variables rather than `var`
- String Templates are awesome, [check them out!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `return` in `formalGreeting()`. Can get rid of the `{}` block in arrow function and anything after `=>` will be returned.

Also missing the function callback for `map()`

```js
var names = ["Will", "Rick", "Blake"];

var formalGreeting = (arr) =>  arr.map(name => "Hello " + name);

console.log(formalGreeting(names))
```